# When i choose manual it doesn't loop again. But when I choose Table it works. What's the error?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I've made this code to display the atomic radius and nuclear number of the main elements

```
import tkinter as tk
import math

#creating list of elements with atomic number - from shrot
elements = [
    {"atomic_number": 1, "symbol": "H", "atomic_radius": 53, "element_name": "Hydrogen"},
    {"atomic_number": 2, "symbol": "He", "atomic_radius": 31, "element_name": "Helium"},
    {"atomic_number": 3, "symbol": "Li", "atomic_radius": 167, "element_name": "Lithium"},
    {"atomic_number": 4, "symbol": "Be", "atomic_radius": 112, "element_name": "Beryllium"},
    {"atomic_number": 5, "symbol": "B", "atomic_radius": 87, "element_name": "Boron"},
    {"atomic_number": 6, "symbol": "C", "atomic_radius": 67, "element_name": "Carbon"},
    {"atomic_number": 7, "symbol": "N", "atomic_radius": 56, "element_name": "Nitrogen"},
    {"atomic_number": 8, "symbol": "O", "atomic_radius": 48, "element_name": "Oxygen"},
    {"atomic_number": 9, "symbol": "F", "atomic_radius": 42, "element_name": "Fluorine"},
    {"atomic_number": 10, "symbol": "Ne", "atomic_radius": 38, "element_name": "Neon"},
    {"atomic_number": 11, "symbol": "Na", "atomic_radius": 190, "element_name": "Sodium"},
    {"atomic_number": 12, "symbol": "Mg", "atomic_radius": 145, "element_name": "Magnesium"},
    {"atomic_number": 13, "symbol": "Al", "atomic_radius": 118, "element_name": "Aluminum"},
] #until 118

loop = 1
def closeLoop():
        global loop
        loop = 0
        #root.destroy()
def choseTable():
        global variable
        variable = 1
        #root.destroy()

    
def choseManual():
        global variable
        variable = 2
        
        
        #root.destroy()
        
def choiceWindow():
        
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.title("Choose choice of input")
        TableButton = tk.Button(root, text='Table',command=lambda: [choseTable(),root.destroy()])
        TableButton.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10,pady=10,sticky=tk.E)
        ManualButton = tk.Button(root, text='Manual Input',command=lambda: [choseManual(),root.destroy()])
        print(variable)
        ManualButton.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=10,pady=10,sticky=tk.W)
        close=tk.Button(root,
                            text='Close',
                            font = ('calibri', 10, 'bold', 'underline'),
                            foreground = 'red',
                            command=lambda: [closeLoop(),root.destroy()])
        close.grid(row =3,rowspan=3,columnspan = 18, padx = 10, pady =20, sticky= tk.EW)
        root.mainloop()
    
def closeOne():
            manual.destroy()
            choiceWindow()
            print(variable)
while (loop==1):
    
    variable = 0
    
    

    choiceWindow()
    if(variable==1):
        # Create the main tkinter window
        pt = tk.Tk()
        pt.title("Table of Elements")

        close=tk.Button(pt,
                        text='Close',
                        font = ('calibri', 10, 'bold', 'underline'),
                        foreground = 'red',
                        command=pt.destroy)
        close.grid(row =21,rowspan=3,columnspan = 18, padx = 10, pady =10, sticky= tk.EW)

        # Function to display element information
        def display_element_info(element):
            nucleus_radius = (1/2)*(math.pow((element['atomic_number']),(1/3)))
            nucleus_radius_str = str(nucleus_radius)
            element_info.config(text=f"{element['element_name']}\n"
                                      f"Element: {element['symbol']}\n"
                                      f"Atomic Number: {element['atomic_number']}\n"
                                      f"Atomic Radius: {element['atomic_radius']} pm\n"
                                      "Nucleus Radius: "+nucleus_radius_str+" fm")

        # Create a grid for the periodic table
        for row in range(7):  
            for col in range(18): 
                index = row * 18 + col
                if index < len(elements):
                    element_button = tk.Button(pt, text=elements[index]["symbol"], width=5, height=2,
                                               command=lambda idx=index: display_element_info(elements[idx]))
                    element_button.grid(row=row, column=col)

        # Label to display element information
        element_info = tk.Label(pt, text="", padx=10, pady=10)
        element_info.grid(row=7, column=0, columnspan=18) 

        # Run the tkinter main loop
        pt.mainloop()
    elif(variable==2):
        manual = tk.Tk()
        manual.title("Atomic and Nucleus number")
        manual.geometry('400x300')

        #close button
        
        close=tk.Button(manual,
                        text='Close',
                        font = ('calibri', 10, 'bold', 'underline'),
                        foreground = 'red',
                        command=lambda:[closeOne()])
        close.grid(row =6, columnspan = 3, padx = 10, pady =10, sticky= tk.EW)
        #function for outputing values
        def elementInfo():
            try:
                #main input of atomic number
                #inp=(inputbox.get("end-1c linestart", "end-1c lineend"))
                inp=(inputbox.get())
                #incase someone enters decimal places
                inpfloat=float(inp)
                #round up decimal places
                inpint=round(inpfloat)
                
                #inpint = int(inpround)
                if(inpint<=118)and(inpint>0):
                    #get item from the list
                    element = elements[inpint-1]

                    #Configure labels

                    #Element name
                    if(inpint<=118)and(inpint>0):
                        lblname.config(text=f"{element['element_name']}")
                    else:
                        lblname.config(text=" ")
                        
                    
                    #Atomic Symbol
                    if(inpint<=118)and(inpint>0):
                        lblsy.config(text=f"Elemental Symbol: {element['symbol']}")
                    else:
                        lblsy.config(text=" ")
                        
                        
                    #Atomic Number
                    if(inpint<=118)and(inpint>0):
                        lblz.config(text=f"Atomic Number: {element['atomic_number']}")
                    else:
                        lblz.config(text=" ")
                                
                    #Atomic Radius
                    if (inpint<113)and(inpint>0):
                        lblar.config(text=f"Atomic Radius: {element['atomic_radius']} pm")
                    elif(inpint>=113):
                        lblar.config(text=f"Atomic Radius not found")
                    else:
                        lblar.config(text=" ")

                    #Nuclear Radius
                    if (inpint<118)and(inpint>0):    
                        #calculate nuclear radius using the formula:
                        #nuclear radius = 1.2*(z^(1/3))
                        nuclear_radius = 1.2*math.pow(inpint, (1/3))
                        #nuclear radius label config
                        nuclear_radius_str = str(nuclear_radius)
                        lblnr.config(text= "Nuclear radius: "+nuclear_radius_str+" fm")
                    else:
                        lblnr.config(text=" ")  
                        
                    #clear textbox
                    #inputbox.delete('1.0', 'end')
                    inputbox.delete('0', 'end')   
                elif(inpint==0)or(inpint>118):
                    lblname.config(text="Not in the perioidic table ")
                    lblsy.config(text=" ")
                    lblz.config(text=" ")
                    lblar.config(text=" ")
                    lblnr.config(text=" ")
                    inputbox.delete('0', 'end')   

            #Error box in case someone enters non numerical value 
            except:
                errorw = tk.Tk()
                errorw.title("error")
                errorw.geometry('400x300')
                inputbox.delete('0', 'end')
                errorbutton = tk.Button(errorw,
                                        height=5,
                                        width=20,
                                        bg = 'red',
                                        text = 'Error, Try Again',
                                        command = errorw.destroy)
                errorbutton.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')


        #main loop
    
        while True:
            try:
                #text box to enter the atomic number

                #Input prompt
                inputprompt = tk.Label(manual, height = 1, text ="Enter the atomic number: ")
                inputprompt.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)
                #Textbox
                '''
                inputbox = tk.Text(manual,
                                   height = 1,
                                   width = 20,
                                   padx=3,
                                   pady=3)
                '''
                inputbox = tk.Entry(manual)
                inputbox.focus_force()
                inputbox.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)
                #Calculate button to display
                searchButton = tk.Button(manual,
                                        text = 'Calculate', 
                                        command = elementInfo)
                searchButton.grid(column=2, row=0, sticky=tk.W)
                
                #crate label for element name
                lblname=tk.Label(manual, text="",font = ('calibri', 10, 'bold', 'underline'))
                lblname.grid(row=1, columnspan =3, padx=5, pady=4, sticky= tk.EW)
                #create label for atomic symbol
                lblsy=tk.Label(manual, text="")
                lblsy.grid(row=2, columnspan =3, padx=5, pady=4, sticky= tk.EW)
                #create label for atomic number
                lblz=tk.Label(manual, text="")
                lblz.grid(row=3, columnspan =3, padx=5, pady=4, sticky = tk.EW)
                #create label for atomic radius
                lblar=tk.Label(manual, text="")
                lblar.grid(row=4, columnspan =3, padx=5, pady=4, sticky= tk.EW)
                #create label for nuclear radius
                lblnr=tk.Label(manual, text="")
                lblnr.grid(row=5, columnspan =3, padx=5, pady=4, sticky = tk.EW)
                #main tkinter loop
                manual.mainloop()
            #Incase somehow there is another error at this point
            #(shouldn't be but you never know)
            except:
                errorw = tk.Tk()
                errorw.title("error")
                errorw.geometry('400x300')
                errorbutton = tk.Button(errorw,
                                        height=5,
                                        width=20,
                                        bg = 'red',
                                        text = 'ErAror, Try Again',
                                        command = errorw.destroy)
                errorbutton.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')
            
    else:
        print("closed")
```

I've tried to put them all in functions but it doesn't work.

Its supposed to keep looping until I click close in the first window but it doesn't. When I open the manual entry and close it, when i try opening it again it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do not use `while loops` together with tkinter, you do not need them! Your application anyway waits for user input. You should create only `one root window` that runs over root.mainloop(). You create a mainloop for every window. I tried to remove everything that I find unnecessary in your code. Try to understand the basic principles of creating a `tkinter app` before you keep going.

```
import tkinter as tk
import math

#creating list of elements with atomic number - from shrot
elements = [
    {"atomic_number": 1, "symbol": "H", "atomic_radius": 53, "element_name": "Hydrogen"},
    {"atomic_number": 2, "symbol": "He", "atomic_radius": 31, "element_name": "Helium"},
    {"atomic_number": 3, "symbol": "Li", "atomic_radius": 167, "element_name": "Lithium"},
    {"atomic_number": 4, "symbol": "Be", "atomic_radius": 112, "element_name": "Beryllium"},
    {"atomic_number": 5, "symbol": "B", "atomic_radius": 87, "element_name": "Boron"},
    {"atomic_number": 6, "symbol": "C", "atomic_radius": 67, "element_name": "Carbon"},
    {"atomic_number": 7, "symbol": "N", "atomic_radius": 56, "element_name": "Nitrogen"},
    {"atomic_number": 8, "symbol": "O", "atomic_radius": 48, "element_name": "Oxygen"},
    {"atomic_number": 9, "symbol": "F", "atomic_radius": 42, "element_name": "Fluorine"},
    {"atomic_number": 10, "symbol": "Ne", "atomic_radius": 38, "element_name": "Neon"},
    {"atomic_number": 11, "symbol": "Na", "atomic_radius": 190, "element_name": "Sodium"},
    {"atomic_number": 12, "symbol": "Mg", "atomic_radius": 145, "element_name": "Magnesium"},
    {"atomic_number": 13, "symbol": "Al", "atomic_radius": 118, "element_name": "Aluminum"},
] #until 118


def createTable():
    # Create the Table window
    pt = tk.Toplevel()
    pt.title("Table of Elements")

    close=tk.Button(pt,
                    text='Close',
                    font = ('calibri', 10, 'bold', 'underline'),
                    foreground = 'red',
                    command=pt.destroy)
    close.grid(row =21,rowspan=3,columnspan = 18, padx = 10, pady =10, sticky= tk.EW)

    # Function to display element information
    def display_element_info(element):
        nucleus_radius = (1/2)*(math.pow((element['atomic_number']),(1/3)))
        nucleus_radius_str = str(nucleus_radius)
        element_info.config(text=f"{element['element_name']}\n"
                                    f"Element: {element['symbol']}\n"
                                    f"Atomic Number: {element['atomic_number']}\n"
                                    f"Atomic Radius: {element['atomic_radius']} pm\n"
                                    "Nucleus Radius: "+nucleus_radius_str+" fm")

    # Create a grid for the periodic table
    for row in range(7):  
        for col in range(18): 
            index = row * 18 + col
            if index < len(elements):
                element_button = tk.Button(pt, text=elements[index]["symbol"], width=5, height=2,
                                            command=lambda idx=index: display_element_info(elements[idx]))
                element_button.grid(row=row, column=col)

    # Label to display element information
    element_info = tk.Label(pt, text="", padx=10, pady=10)
    element_info.grid(row=7, column=0, columnspan=18) 



def createManual():

    #function for outputing values
    def elementInfo():
        try:
            #main input of atomic number
            #inp=(inputbox.get("end-1c linestart", "end-1c lineend"))
            inp=(inputbox.get())
            #incase someone enters decimal places
            inpfloat=float(inp)
            #round up decimal places
            inpint=round(inpfloat)
            
            #inpint = int(inpround)
            if(inpint<=118)and(inpint>0):
                #get item from the list
                element = elements[inpint-1]

                #Configure labels

                #Element name
                if(inpint<=118)and(inpint>0):
                    lblname.config(text=f"{element['element_name']}")
                else:
                    lblname.config(text=" ")
                    
                
                #Atomic Symbol
                if(inpint<=118)and(inpint>0):
                    lblsy.config(text=f"Elemental Symbol: {element['symbol']}")
                else:
                    lblsy.config(text=" ")
                    
                    
                #Atomic Number
                if(inpint<=118)and(inpint>0):
                    lblz.config(text=f"Atomic Number: {element['atomic_number']}")
                else:
                    lblz.config(text=" ")
                            
                #Atomic Radius
                if (inpint<113)and(inpint>0):
                    lblar.config(text=f"Atomic Radius: {element['atomic_radius']} pm")
                elif(inpint>=113):
                    lblar.config(text=f"Atomic Radius not found")
                else:
                    lblar.config(text=" ")

                #Nuclear Radius
                if (inpint<118)and(inpint>0):    
                    #calculate nuclear radius using the formula:
                    #nuclear radius = 1.2*(z^(1/3))
                    nuclear_radius = 1.2*math.pow(inpint, (1/3))
                    #nuclear radius label config
                    nuclear_radius_str = str(nuclear_radius)
                    lblnr.config(text= "Nuclear radius: "+nuclear_radius_str+" fm")
                else:
                    lblnr.config(text=" ")  
                    
                #clear textbox
                #inputbox.delete('1.0', 'end')
                inputbox.delete('0', 'end')   
            elif(inpint==0)or(inpint>118):
                lblname.config(text="Not in the perioidic table ")
                lblsy.config(text=" ")
                lblz.config(text=" ")
                lblar.config(text=" ")
                lblnr.config(text=" ")
                inputbox.delete('0', 'end')   

        #Error box in case someone enters non numerical value 
        except:
            errorw = tk.Tk()
            errorw.title("error")
            errorw.geometry('400x300')
            inputbox.delete('0', 'end')
            errorbutton = tk.Button(errorw,
                                    height=5,
                                    width=20,
                                    bg = 'red',
                                    text = 'Error, Try Again',
                                    command = errorw.destroy)
            errorbutton.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')


    manual = tk.Toplevel()
    manual.title("Atomic and Nucleus number")
    manual.geometry('400x300')
    
    close=tk.Button(manual,
                    text='Close',
                    font = ('calibri', 10, 'bold', 'underline'),
                    foreground = 'red',
                    command=manual.destroy)
    close.grid(row =6, columnspan = 3, padx = 10, pady =10, sticky= tk.EW)

    inputprompt = tk.Label(manual, height = 1, text ="Enter the atomic number: ")
    inputprompt.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)
    #Textbox
    '''
    inputbox = tk.Text(manual,
                        height = 1,
                        width = 20,
                        padx=3,
                        pady=3)
    '''
    inputbox = tk.Entry(manual)
    inputbox.focus_force()
    inputbox.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)
    #Calculate button to display
    searchButton = tk.Button(
        manual,
        text = 'Calculate', 
        command = elementInfo
        )
    searchButton.grid(column=2, row=0, sticky=tk.W)
    
    #crate label for element name
    lblname=tk.Label(manual, text="",font = ('calibri', 10, 'bold', 'underline'))
    lblname.grid(row=1, columnspan =3, padx=5, pady=4, sticky= tk.EW)
    #create label for atomic symbol
    lblsy=tk.Label(manual, text="")
    lblsy.grid(row=2, columnspan =3, padx=5, pady=4, sticky= tk.EW)
    #create label for atomic number
    lblz=tk.Label(manual, text="")
    lblz.grid(row=3, columnspan =3, padx=5, pady=4, sticky = tk.EW)
    #create label for atomic radius
    lblar=tk.Label(manual, text="")
    lblar.grid(row=4, columnspan =3, padx=5, pady=4, sticky= tk.EW)
    #create label for nuclear radius
    lblnr=tk.Label(manual, text="")
    lblnr.grid(row=5, columnspan =3, padx=5, pady=4, sticky = tk.EW)


######## create ONE root window, with ONE mainloop
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Choose choice of input")

TableButton = tk.Button(root, text='Table',command=createTable)
TableButton.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10,pady=10,sticky=tk.E)

ManualButton = tk.Button(root, text='Manual Input',command=createManual)
ManualButton.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=10,pady=10,sticky=tk.W)

close=tk.Button(
    root,
    text='Close',
    font = ('calibri', 10, 'bold', 'underline'),
    foreground = 'red',
    command=root.destroy
    )
close.grid(row =3,rowspan=3,columnspan = 18, padx = 10, pady =20, sticky= tk.EW)

root.mainloop()
```